# Retrieving contents inside JMS Queue for within specific time inteval

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I need to create an application wherein I have to retrieve all the elements inside the JMS queue within a given time limit.

For instance, the given the limit is 10 seconds. So every 10 seconds, the application should create a new `Thread` wherein the `Thread` is responsible for 1) connecting to the JMS queue and 2) retrieving all the messages during the time of connection.

So in 10 seconds, lets say that there were 15 `TextMessage`s in the queue. I only want the current executing thread to retrieve those 15 `TextMessages` and nothing else. I'm afraid that the thread would pick up additional messages.

Is there a facility to limit how much messages a consumer can take? Maybe something feature which would let me see how much the queue contains?

Answer (score 0):

One method I can think of is that you create a receiver from a session that uses `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` acknowledgement mode. Now start the receiver and receive the messages. Yes you will receive some additional messages. Now as you receive a message get it `JMSTimestamp` and see whether it belongs to the time duration your thread is interested in. If the message is as per your time requirement acknowledge it. If not do not acknowledge it in which case it will persist on the server and may be picked up by other threads looking for messages with different time stamps.

Another efficient way would be using message selector. Since `JMSTimestamp` is a message header and can be used in a selector you can take advantage of it. Create receiver with a selector on `JMSTimestamp` with your time range requirement. Only messages satisfying the selector will be received.